# How to automaticaly remove files inside a folder inside folder?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a parent folder ***raw csv files***

***raw csv files*** folder contains multiple folders named ***a,b,c...z***

***a,b,c...z*** folders: they all contain lot of ***csv files***

how do i automatically remove these ***csv files***,from each folder, which are more than 30 days old ?

looking for a ***bash script*** that i can put as a ***cron job***

Comment: Note that, on Unix/BSD--and Linux, too--these are "directories" and not the user/Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to your cron to remove all csv files that are older than 30 days, from the folder "raw csv files", everyday at 10:20

```
20 10 * * *  /usr/bin/find "raw csv files" -name \*.csv -mtime +30 -delete
```

Comment: what is **-name**

Comment: `-name` is the pattern that would identify the files to be deleted. In this case. it is `\*.csv` so that it would match all csv files

Comment: the **csv** files are inside folders(a,b,c) inside **raw csv files**..So would \*.csv work?

Comment: how to delete the folders(a,b,c) also ?